# Laravel: How to register an own implementation of `DatabaseManager` and `Connection`

Tags: laravel, eloquent, dependency-injection, database-connection, laravel-service-container

Due to debugging reasons (I am hunting down a very weird bug), I need to extend the Laravel classes `Illuminate\Database\DatabaseManager`, `Illuminate\Database\Connection`, and `Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder`.

Hence, I created the following three classes in my application.

```php
namespace App\Database;

use Illuminate\Database\DatabaseManager as BaseDatabaseManager;

class DatabaseManager extends BaseDatabaseManager {
  public static bool $isDebugEnabled = false;

  // ...
  // Overwrites some methods of the base class which prints additional diagnostic information
  // if `self::$isDebugEnabled === true`.
  // ...
}
```

and

```php
namespace App\Database;

use Illuminate\Database\Connection as BaseConnection;

class Connection extends BaseConnection {
  public static bool $isDebugEnabled = false;

  /**
   * Get a new query builder instance.
   *
   * This returns our own extended query builder with instrumentation.
   *
   * @return Query\Builder
   */
  public function query(): Query\Builder {
    return new Query\Builder(
      $this, $this->getQueryGrammar(), $this->getPostProcessor()
    );
  }


  // ...
  // Overwrites some methods of the base class which prints additional diagnostic information
  // if `self::$isDebugEnabled === true`.
  // ...
}
```

and

```php
namespace App\Database\Query;

use Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder as BaseBuilder;

class Builder extends BaseBuilder {
  public static bool $isDebugEnabled = false;

  // ...
  // Overwrites some methods of the base class which prints additional diagnostic information
  // if `self::$isDebugEnabled === true`.
  // ...
}
```

**How do I register my custom `DatabaseManager` and `Connection` with the Laravel Service Container instead of the original parent classes?** The original classes are registered in `\Illuminate\Foundation\Application::registerCoreContainerAliases()` which is called by the constructor of the `Application` object, i.e. these classes are registered at a very early stage.

I thought that I could "re-register" my classes in `\App\Providers\AppServiceProvider::register` like this

```php
namespace App\Providers;

class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
  /**
   * Register any application services.
   *
   * @return void
   */
  public function register() {
    // Overwrite core container services with our own classes
    // for debugging purposes
    // See \Illuminate\Foundation\Application::registerCoreContainerAliases()
    $this->app->alias('db', \App\Database\DatabaseManager::class);
    $this->app->alias('db.connection', \App\Database\Connection::class);
  }
}
```

but it did not work. The original classes are still being used. I used `app->alias`, because this is what `registerCoreContainerAliases` originally uses, too. But I also tried `->bind` with no success.

After some debugging I found out that `->alias` and `->bind` do not overwrite a previously registered binding, but simply add a new binding to the end of the list. Hence, the previously registered services by the Laravel core application are still preferential.

What is the correct solution?

Comment: I think for your purpose it makes no sense to make own implementation of the Laravel core classes. Instead, you could debug the problem by setting the breakpoints right in these core classes and watching the stack with xdebug. Or, just by making the temporary dumps with dump() in these classes. Btw, what is the original bug? Probably there is a better solution for it...

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot reproduce the bug otherwise I would already have used Xdebug. The problem only occurs on specific setups of a couple of users and the users have no debugging capabilities. So I need to add instrumentation code do to some in-the-field logging. Basically, Laravel seems to "swallow" certain DB results silently without raising a proper error. I have already got DB dumps and configs from customers, rebuilt their setup and the problem was not re-producible locally. Anyway, the original question posted here is interesting on its own right. So we should stick to the question.

Comment: you can try with app()->extend instead of alias() method. Look at this article: https://orobogenius.medium.com/extending-core-laravel-bindings-97f409140fc3